# Riemann and Lebesgue integrals of multivalued function

Tags: analysis, multivalued-functions

Riemann integral of multivalued function is defined as limit in Hausdorff metric if it doesn't depend of partition.
Lebesgue integral is defined as a set of all integrals of selectors for which the Lebesgue integral exists. Is there the same relation between them as for single-valued functions?